# git does not exclude .git directory

Tags: git

I'm trying to use version control in my music folder to track how I sort it and when I add/delete music. I only need the metadata and not the contents in the repo.

To achieve this, I'm using `tree` to maintain two text files that are in `.list` in the root directory for the repo.

This is the script run by cron every 15 minutes:

```
cd /home/user/folder/ && tree -faRn -o /home/user/folder/.list/1
cd /home/user/folder/ && tree -faRhupsDn --du -o /home/user/folder/.list/2
git -C /home/user/folder add .list
git -C /home/user/folder commit -m $a
```

It's also monitoring the `.git` folder (!) and this means that it's committing everytime the script runs. Should I add .git to a gitignore? Why is it watching the `.git` folder anyway? is it because my directory is named `.list`? Do I need to double quote it? `.list` isn't a git repo.

[image: tig output]

---

**Thanks, kusalananda!**

Here's the modified (and working!) script:

```
cd /home/user/folder/ && tree -faRn -I '.git|.list' -o /home/user/folder/.list/1
cd /home/user/folder/ && tree -faRhupsDn -I '.git|.list' --du -o /home/user/folder/.list/2
git -C /home/user/folder add .list
git -C /home/user/folder commit -m $a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `tree` that looks into the `.git` directory.

You will want to tell `tree` to ignore the `.git` directory.  On the Ubuntu machine that I have access to, this is done with

```
tree -I '.git' ...other options...
```

You may also want to have it ignore the `.list` folder.

Comment: How did I miss that?

Comment: @PatrickBateman Head-too-full-induced selective blindness. Happens to me on the best of days. Hmm... "Inattentional blindness" is a thing it seems.